# Why doesn't work this sass task in my gruntfile.js?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

This task doesn't do anything:

```js
sass: {
  options: {
    style: 'expanded',
    sourceMap: true,
    importer: compass
    //includePaths: sassLib
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'scss',
      src: ['globbed/style.scss'],
      dest: 'css',
      ext: '.style.css'
    }]
  }
},
```

But this is working, it compiles the `style.scss` to `style.css`:

```js
sass: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'css/style.css': 'scss/globbed/style.scss',
    }
  }
}
```

What should I modify in the first task?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the `options` object into the `dist` one. Alternatively, since you are using Compass, you could try to use the [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) module for an easier approach. In your case the code could be:

```js
// ...
compass: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            sassDir: "scss",
            cssDir: "css",
            relativeAssets: true,
            outputStyle: "expanded"
        }
    }
},
// ...
```